# Is UseIISPlatformHandler() deprecated correctly to UseIIS()?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

In [this place](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/164), there's information on changes to Core as follows.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
{
  ...
  // Remove call to app.UseIISPlatformHandler(); This is handled by UseIIS in Main.
  // Remove call to app.UseForwardedHeaders(); This is handled by UseIIS in Main.
  ...
}
```

However, when checking out the contents of the method, there's no such call as *UseIIS()*. The nearest is the one to *UseIISIntegration()* but it's commented as if it substitutes *UseForwardedHeaders()*.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseDefaultConfiguration(args)
    .UseServer("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel")
    // Replaces call to UseIISPlatformHandlerUrl()
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();

  host.Run();
}
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest ASP.NET Core tooling? If I create a project (I have the latest), I see none of those comments. And yes, UseIISIntegration is correct

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Oh, sorry if I was unclear. The comments are visible in the code sample on the project's site that I linked to. I'm guessing, just like you said, that it's an obsolete version. Google doesn't know which is "the latest" and I'm too ignorant to decide. Hence the confusion. I guess you can post it as a reply so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is rather old and some things have changed since then. You are on the right track, though.

The `UseIISPlatformHandler` call indeed moved from Startup to Program start and has been renamed to `UseIISIntegration`.

Comment: Has there ever been something like *UseIIS()* in some of the subversions? Or is it a typo in the docs?

Comment: Yes, I guess it's a typo. They refer to `UseIISIntegration` in the code example as well.

Comment: Hmm... I can call UseIIS() so I don't think it's a typo. I'm trying to figure out what the difference is though between the 2 calls. Anyone know?

Comment: @BVernon `UseIIS()` is for  [In-process hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#in-process-hosting-model) and `UseIISIntegration()`is for [Out-of-process hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#out-of-process-hosting-model).